# Mongoose update database record using async/await promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, mongoose, async-await

I'm using Mongoose and NodeJs and I've problem with my REST API. I'm not sure how can I update records using async/await promise. Here's my code:

```
update: async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
    const {
        login,
        image
    } = req.body

    const user = await User.findOne({
        login
    })
    if (!user) return res.status(403).send({
        error: 'Could not find the user'
    })

    user.image = image // this is obviously not working at all

    try {
        await user.save() // doesn't save my super image profile
        return res.status(201).json({
            message: 'Profile photo has been updated'
        })
    } catch (err) {
        throw new Error(err)
    }
},
```

How can I update this record using async/await promise? Is that even possible?

Comment: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/promises.html

Comment: @PrerakSola thank you! I've found error in my user model.

Comment: @cccn Why don't you use the `findOneAndUpdate` function? It will help